# Jsonata predicate to filter objects without a specific property

Tags: jsonata

Consider the following source data

```json
[
  {
    "a": 1
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 1
  }
]
```

Here's a query to filter objects that have a property `b`:

```json
$[`b`]
```

It returns

```json
{
  "a": 2,
  "b": 1
}
```

But how to get objects that HAVE NO property `b`?

Something like

```json
$[$not(`b`)]
```

just give `** no match **`

And I'm out of ideas (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simplest solution: `$[$not($exists(b))]`

Comment: Wow, thanks! I've missed the `$exists()` func completely

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$exists](https://docs.jsonata.org/boolean-functions#exists) function to check if a certain property is not present, like that:

```
$[$not(b ~> $exists)]
```

Check it out on the Stedi playground: https://stedi.link/58kEjJN

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Same as from @Worldexe but I prefer a less functional way